# How do I tie a foreign key to an object?

Tags: django, django-models

i have a model `Order`,

```
class Order(SmartModel):
    date = models.DateTimeField(...)
    status = models.IntegerField(...)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant,null=True,blank=True,default = None,help_text="The restaurant the customer order from")
    email = models.EmailField(...)
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(...)
```

i am saving the the object like so,

```
orders = Order()
    checkout_form = forms.CheckoutForm(request.POST,instance=orders)
    orders = checkout_form.save(commit=False)
    anon_user = User.objects.get(id=settings.ANONYMOUS_USER_ID)
    orders.created_by = anon_user
    orders.modified_by = anon_user
    orders.status = Order.SUBMITTED
    orders.save()
```

As you can i see i have not saved the restaurant(fk field), how should i go about that. i have looked at this (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-users/PcSDKZhPVmc) and several other examples but they are confusing me the more.

i need to tie ~Restaurant~ to order so that when i lookup an order i know which restaurant it belongs to.

annoying thing is i have failed to load djangoproject.com, its been a week.

forms.py,

```
class CheckoutForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        exclude = ('created_by','modified_by','is_active','status','restaurant','date')
```

template,

```
<table>
  {{ form.errors }}
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}
  {% form_table_row form.email %}
  {% form_table_row form.mobile %}
  </table>
```

Comment: where's the template and forms.py codes

Comment: @catherine i just did

Comment: why you exclude restaurant in your form if you want it?

Comment: its a foreignkey field, i don't think it belongs in form that a customer is filling in and also, the thing is by the time the customer gets to fill in the form, they have already chosen a restaurant.

Comment: Ok you want to select first the restaurant before ordering. Is that the complete codes for your views? or there are codes that you didn't post?

Comment: that is complete code for saving the `Order`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I will be just guessing here or create sample scenario:

After the user create information and select their restaurant. They must go on the next form where the user select their order. The restaurant id must pass in the next form so that when the user submit the order, we will use that restaurant id in saving their order.

```
def save_order(request, restaurant_id):
    anon_user = User.objects.get(id=settings.ANONYMOUS_USER_ID)
    orders = Order(restaurant_id=restaurant_id)

    checkout_form = forms.CheckoutForm(request.POST, instance=orders)
    checkout = checkout_form.save(commit=False)

    checkout.created_by = anon_user
    checkout.modified_by = anon_user
    checkout.status = Order.SUBMITTED
    checkout.save()
```

Comment: this is more like it but there is no field orders.restaurant_id.., if am to do this how should i go about it in the urls.py

Comment: url, is like so, `url(r'^checkout/$',show_checkout,name="checkout")`

Comment: `orders.restaurant_id` is from your `Order model` not in your form so don't worry if you exclude that in your form. They are different. To be able to pass the id you have to modified the your url so that it can pass the restaurant_id

Comment: Wait I will modified your view for restaurant id

Answer (score 0):

In your view you need to get the `Restaurant` object and save that in `order`. As you haven't shown complete view code, I'm not sure exactly how to get the `Restaurant` object.

Here is sample code ...

```
orders = Order()
checkout_form = forms.CheckoutForm(request.POST,instance=orders)
orders = checkout_form.save(commit=False)

#get restaurant obj
restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(name = "some_restaurant")
orders.restaurant = restaurant

anon_user = User.objects.get(id=settings.ANONYMOUS_USER_ID)
orders.created_by = anon_user
orders.modified_by = anon_user
orders.status = Order.SUBMITTED
orders.save()
```

Comment: i dont want to get restaurant by name because there will be several restaurants you know.. and the other code i didnt include is not necessary...

Comment: @SuziemacTani, you need to get restaurant object somehow, either by querying by name or some other field.